# Set environment variable for babel ios bundle build per scheme in React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I want to set a certain environment variable per scheme to be available inside babel.config.js so that I can turn a certain plugin on or off. How can I achieve this? I already tried setting the variable inside the `PBXShellScriptBuildPhase` phase but it applies to all schemes.

Comment: Do you want a variable for different build environments? (debug, release) ?

Comment: Sure, if that helps me in getting a certain env var inside babel config file during archive process. @Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `user defined` setting in `Build Settings` tab, for each scheme, and then include that as a key inside `Info.plist` file. Then create header and implementation file to export this variable to react native side. Like so,

```swift
// RNConfig.h

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNConfig : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

```swift
// RNConfig.m


#import "RNConfig.h"

@implementation RNConfig

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
  NSString* custom_val = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"YOUR_CUSTOM_VALUE"];

  return @{@"custom": buildEnvironment };
}

@end
```

Then you can just import the config from Native modules as

```js
const { RNConfig } = NativeModules;
```

and use the variable inside the babel config file

Comment: importing react-native inside babel config throws following error
`Error while loading config - Cannot find module 'warnOnce'.Error while loading config - Cannot find module 'warnOnce'.`